# Javascript iterate through all checkboxes on submit, and set attribute if changed from original value

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am trying to make a javascript function similar to the following, except it will iterate through all the checkboxes when the user clicks the submit button:

```
$('.checkboxstatus').click(function(){
this.setAttribute('checked',this.checked);
if (this.checked && $(this).data("def") == 0){
             //checkbox has changed
            this.setAttribute('changed', 'yes');
    }
    else if(!this.checked && $(this).data("def") == 'checked')
    {
            //checkbox has changed
            this.setAttribute('changed', 'yes');
    }
    else{
        //no change in checkbox
        this.setAttribute('changed', 'no');
        }
 });
```

When the user clicks submit, the function should be called and it should iterate through all checkboxes and see if the checkbox is checked and see if the data-def is checked or 0. If the checkbox is checked and data-def="checked" then nothing should happen. If the checkbox state is different from the data-def then an attribute ("changed") should be added to that checkbox with value of "yes". Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question almost gives you the answer. You need to attach a "submit" event handler to the form, then grab all `input[type=checkbox]` and set the "changed" attribute accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get this, but the usual way to do something like this would be to set an initial state in `data`, then on submit, prevent the submit action, check all the checkboxes against that initial state `data` variable, and see if anything changed, if it did, trigger the native submit handler ?

```
var boxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
    $(this).data('initial_state', this.checked);
});

$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var same_same = true;

    boxes.each(function() {
        if ( $(this).data('initial_state') !== this.checked ) { // has changed ?
            $(this).data('changed', true);
            same_same = false;
        }
    });

    if ( ! same_same ) { // diffelent
        this.submit();
    } else {
       alert('same same, but not diffelent!');
    }

 });
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track, what we are comparing the checked state of the boxes to is the data-def attribute on each checkbox